# Meteor Rubaxa:Sortable Nested Field

Tags: javascript, meteor, rubaxa-sortable

I am trying to use the meteor rubaxa:sortable package to make a list sortable in my meteor app.

The list I am attempting to sort is actually nested in a document in Curriculums.  It looks like this...

```
{'id' : 123,
 'cratedAt' : timestamp, 
 'resources' : object
}
```

the resources objects look like this

```
{'id' : 232, 'order' : 1}, {'id': 344, 'order' : 2} ....
```

I used a helper function to pull the one item from curriculums I want to display.

```
return CurriculumList.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
```

Then use `{{#sortable items=resources}}` in my template.  The output is just like the `{{#each}}`, and the items are draggable and sortable.  However when I look at the console, i recieve this error:

`rubaxa_sortable.js:1333 
Uncaught TypeError: templateInstance.collection.findOne is not a function`

How can I make this package properly update my 'order' field?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `resources` is an array. For a solution, refer to the workaround in [Issue #287](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/287) on GitHub.

[Issue #194](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/194), which points to Issue #287, contains [a MeteorPad example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/2HNubn2kuavjiQ7DW/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard) very similar to the example you give.

Also, the person who opened [GitHub Issue #539](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/539) is getting the same error and equates it to the problem in Issue #194.

Note, as well, that according to [Issue #366](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/366), you get the same error if the collection is empty.